# Redeploy plugin into eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

I have a eclipse plugin that contains JUnit Tests developed using SWTBot.

I'm trying to run the test against a eclipse installation using tycho-surefire-plugin on a hadless mode. Here is my maven conviguration:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
 <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${tycho-version}</version>
   <configuration>
   <useUIThread>false</useUIThread>
   <testRuntime>p2Installed</testRuntime>
   <work>${work.dir}</work>
   <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
   <useUIThread>false</useUIThread>
   <argLine>${ui.test.args}</argLine>
   <appArgLine>${ui.test.vmargs}</appArgLine>
   <application>com.myapplication</application>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm running test using:

```
mvn verify
```

Everything is ok except that fact that if I'm doing some code change on my plugin the newer version of the code is not deployed into eclipse installation.
Before running mvn verify I'm running a mvn install command.
If I'm adding a new test class I get

```
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.util.NestedRuntimeException: Unable to create test class 'com.tests.MyNewClassTest'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

I there any configuration that I'm missing. How can I redeploy test plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Incremental builds, i.e. builds without `clean` require that the build plug-ins correctly cope with the build results in the target folder from the previous execution. This is apparently not the case for the tycho-surefire-plugin.

Comment: Feature requests can be filed here: [Tycho issue tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho)